# htaccess redirect query string to a path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

So i have a htaccess rewrite that makes a query string to a path like so..

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?query=$1
```

This works fine and using the above i can access the page via both ***page.php?query=*** and ***/page/query/*** but how can i make it so that if the page is accessed by the ***page.php?query=*** method, it automatically redirects to the path version?

I've tried the following but i don't think i wrote it correctly...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.webaddress\.com\/page\.php\?query\=$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.webaddress.com/page/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following

```
RewriteEngine On
#url redirection from old url to the new one
#redirect /page.php?query=foo to /page/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page.php\?query=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /page/%1? [L,R]
#url rewiring from new url to the old one
# rewrite /page/foo to /page.php?query=foo
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it before your internal rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)\=(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%2/%3? [R=301]
```